# How can I use migrations to move data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a scenario where I need to move the data from one model **(Old model where some data already exist)** to another model and in turn to another model if necessary.how can I add this process in migration file so,that I can accomplish the requirement with just `python manage.py migrate` command.

this is the model where All the old items exist:

```
class UserFavorite(CreatedAtMixin):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

objects = UserFavoriteManager()

def __str__(self):
    try:
        return str(self.content_object)
    except AttributeError:
        return 'None'

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = "date_added"
    unique_together = ("user", "content_type", "object_id")`
```

Here is the model where I need to insert item first, per item in above model:

```
class CollectionItem(models.Model):

sort_number=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
type=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False, blank=False)
item_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=models.Q(app_label='news', model='News') | models.Q(app_label='work', model='Work') | models.Q(app_label='collection', model='Quote'))
item_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
item = generic.GenericForeignKey('item_type', 'item_id')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Collection Item"
    verbose_name_plural = "Collection Items"
def __str__(self):
    return self.item.title
```

then I need to insert that into:

```
class Collections(CreatedAtMixin):
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='collections_user')
collection_place=models.ForeignKey('companies.CompanyOffice',related_name='collections_place',null=True)
collection_name = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=False, blank=False)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
items=models.ManyToManyField('collection.CollectionItem')
def __str__(self):
    return self.collection_name

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("user","collection_name")
    verbose_name = "Collection"
    verbose_name_plural = "Collections"
    ordering = [ '-created_at']
    get_latest_by = "created_at"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write your new models and [create a schema migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#workflow).

Then [create a data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) and write the required code to transfert your old models data to the new models (hint: if possible, also write the code to revert your migration).

Finally - assuming the old models are not used anymore -, remove the old models code and create a last schema migration.

The details are all documented in the above links, and what's left is specific to your application so we cannot help further.